# POST requests with a Jersey client

Tags: java, http-headers, jersey, content-type, url-encoding

I've just started using the Jersey framework and would like to use a Jersey client to send an HTTP request with the `content-type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The two options below result in two slightly different requests.

```
// webTarget is a WebTarget instance, already configured

Form form = new Form();
form.param("some-string", "some string");
Response response1 = webTarget.request().header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").post(Entity.form(form));


Response response2 = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).post(Entity.entity("some-string=some string, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
```

The first option results in a body that looks like:

```
some-string=some+string
```

The second option results in a body that looks like:

```
some-string=some string
```

Why is there a difference? Should they not be the same?

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on, you first need to understand the component that handles (de)serialization. For serialization, a [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) is used, and for deserialization, a [`MessageBodyReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) is used. You can read more at [`JAX-RS Entity Providers`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html).

That said there are different `MessageBodyWriter`s for `Form` and for `String`, namely [`FormProvider`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/FormProvider.java) and [`StringMessageProvider`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/StringMessageProvider.java), respectively. The former [url-encodes the values](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/AbstractFormProvider.java#L96), while the latter [does not](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java#L129).

Comment: Why doesn't `StringMessageProvider` url encode the value? It takes the media type as a parameter. Is that a bug?

Comment: Because there are a bunch of use cases for String, e.g JSON, XML, etc. All of those can be handle by a String. It's trivial to convert a String to the bytes for the output stream. It is not worried about trying to figure out a data type. It is not meant for any specific type. Thats what the different type providers are for.

Comment: Not user how a user is expected to know that. Looking at the API, which takes a media type, suggests that URL encoding is supported for String.

Comment: So, if I want the request to be URL encoded, I should use a Form?

Comment: Yes or MultivaluedMap

Answer (score 0):

In second case, you have used webTarget.request().

This is what documentation says about this method:

Invocation.Builder request(MediaType... acceptedResponseTypes)
Start building a request to the targeted web resource and define the **accepted response media types**.

It would not encode the parameters.